# how to inhert a class style to child elements of applied element

Tags: html, css, fonts

What is the "best" (performance, reasonable) way to apply a font to this html:

```
<nav role="navigation" class="pseudoTableHeader mainNavigation pepColorBackground">
<header class="hide">
    <h1>Navigation</h1>
</header>
<ul class="centeredList">
    <li><a href="#">Wir &uuml;ber uns</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Spendenformate</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Neues aus der Redaktion</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Autoren</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Impressum</a></li>
</ul>
```

Version 1:
http://jsfiddle.net/vnQcv/

Version 2:
http://jsfiddle.net/vnQcv/1/

Version 3:
http://jsfiddle.net/vnQcv/2/

Version 4:
???

Answer (score -1):

Better to just include it as css in the html

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm not clear, I did not ask how to include a font. Please look at the examples.